# Cassandra 2+ HPC Deployment

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

I am trying to deploy Cassandra on a Linux Based HPC cluster and I need some guidelines if possible. Specifically, what is the difference between running Cassandra locally and in cluster.

When managing locally (in which case it runs smoothly) we duplicate the original files for every node inside our Cassandra directory and we apply the appropriate changes for IP address, rcp, JMX etc... however, when managing a network which files do we need to install in each node. The whole package with all the files or just some of the required ones 
like, bin/cassandra.in.sh, conf/cassandra.yaml, bin/cassandra.

I am a little bit confused on what to store in each node separately so to start working on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Cassandra on each node (VM), i.e. the whole package and then update config files as neccessary. As described [here](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/initialize/initializeSingleDS.html) to configure cluster in a single data center you need:

- Install Cassandra on each node
- Configure cluster name
- Configure seeds
- Configure snitch, if needed